# Rotate object to match trajectory

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am learning about vectors and how to move objects with them in ThreeJS. As a simple experiment I am launching a box using a velocity and an arbitrary gravity vector.

I am also trying to orient the object so that it matches the curved path it is following, it looks like it starts correct but then starts to turn back after half way.

Also the examples I've been learning from are not in JS they do things like:

```
position = position + velocity * delta;
velocity = velocity + gravity * delta;
```

But you cannot do the same thing in JS, so I have been multiplying by a scalar, am I on the right track here?

Here is my render function:

```
function render(){
    var delta = clock.getDelta();

    velocity.add(velocity.clone().multiplyScalar(delta));
    velocity.add(gravity.clone().multiplyScalar(delta));

    box.position.add(velocity);

    var theta = velocity.angleTo(z);
    box.rotation.x = (theta);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

**UPDATE:** Here's what I ended up doing based on WaclawJasper answer **[JSFIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/db6j8pc3/11/)**

```
function render(){
    var delta = clock.getDelta();

    velocity.addScaledVector(gravity, delta);
    position.add(velocity);

    axis.crossVectors(up, velocity.clone().normalize()).normalize();
    radians = Math.acos(up.dot(velocity.clone().normalize()));
    box.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(axis, radians);

    box.position.set(position.x, position.y, position.z);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS doesnt support operator overloading but `position = position + velocity * delta` basically means add delta multiply by velocity to position. In other languages, operations can have different meaning based on the type of each argument. Here since delta is a number and velocity is vec3 it means to scale the vector. Fortunately ThreeJS does provide `addScaledVector` that does this for you.

As for the rotation, the simplest way to do it is to change the orientation so that the direction the model is facing is equal to its velocity. And the function to do that is `matrix4.lookAt`. `matrix4.lookAt(v3(0,0,0),velocity, UP)` should give you the correct rotation matrix and all you have to do is apply it to the model.